# Python class design with metaclass

Tags: python, oop, metaclass

I have a class design where the `Children` classes inheriting from a certain `Parent` class just differ in some `parameters`, but the `Parent` class contains all methods, which are using the `parameters` provided as class variables on the `Children`. So, in other words, each of my `Child` classes is fully described by the list of `parameters` and the inheritance of the `Parent` class.

So, let's say, I have the following classes:

```py
class Parent():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for param in self.__class__.parameters:
            self.setattr(param, kwargs.get(param))

    def compare(self, other):
        for param in self.__class__.parameters:
            if self.getattr(param) != other.getattr(param):
                return False
        return True

class ChildA(Parent):
    parameters = ["length", "height", "width"]
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


class ChildB(Parent):
    parameters = ["color", "taste"]
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

My actual classes are a bit different - I have more and more complex methods on the `Parent` class and also different kinds of parameters - , but this is sort of a minimum example of the design principle.

Since `Parent` class is relying on its `Children` to have the class variable `parameters`, I thought, I might want to enforce the existence of the class variable on each `Child` class. I have read that I achieve this by using a metaclass. But I have also read that most developers do not need to use metaclasses, and if in doubt, you probably don't need them. I have never worked with metaclasses before, and so I am in doubt whether I should use them, and so by that rule mentioned, I probably do not need a metaclass. But on the other hand, the term "metaclass" just sounds like a good match to my structure, since `Parent` really looks like something which could well be called "metaclass" in some sense (technically, not in terms of the way the terminus technicus *metaclass* is used in OOP, but in terms of: it is fully describing the behaviour of the children classes).

So, I wonder: Is there a different (better) design of classes to reflect my structure? Should I use a metaclass to enforce the existence of the `parameters`, or is there a better way to do so? Or should I just resign to enforce the existence of the `parameters` class variable on the Children classes in the first place?

Comment: Why would you not define interfaces (or for that matter actual method implementations) in the parent class that deal with the parameters visible to the parent and override them in the child class dealing with additional parameters in the child class?

Comment: @Sharad: In my situation, I have a bunch of methods and a bunch of Child classes. I would like to avoid the need to implement the methods on each Child class. The idea of that design is to avoid repetitive code on each Child class. But I am not sure, whether I fully understood what you mean. Could you make an example? That would help me clearly understanding you, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using python3.6 or above, you can accomplish this using [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__) which I personally reason better with than a metaclass.

An example of `__init_subclass__` based on the usecase described:

```
class Parent:
    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'parameters'):
          raise TypeError(f'Subclass of {cls} does not have a parameters class attribute')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for param in self.__class__.parameters:
            self.setattr(param, kwargs.get(param))

    def compare(self, other):
        for param in self.__class__.parameters:
            if self.getattr(param) != other.getattr(param):
                return False
        return True


class GoodChild(Parent):
    parameters = ['length', 'height', 'width']


class BadChild(Parent):
    pass
```

Which results in raising a `TypeError` exception when the `BadChild` class is created (not when it is instantiated):

```
TypeError: Subclass of <class '__main__.BadChild'> does not have a parameters class attribute
```